# File Download Smartface 4.5

Tags: smartface.io

I have downloaded  [Sample Project](https://github.com/smartface/Sample-Projects) for file upload and download but it does not work file download for ios and android. Is the bug still going on for this relase also? If not could you share a working code for picture download sample code?

Answer (score 1):

You can use following codes for file download.It works fine for me.Also, you can reach sample codes from the [guides](https://www.smartface.io/developer/guides/advanced/file-download-upload/#database).

```
var webClientDownload = new SMF.Net.WebClient({
        url : "http://services.smartface.io/File/Download/javascript.js",
        httpMethod : "GET",
        autoFileSave : true,
        onSyndicationSuccess : function (e) {
            alert("downloaded Javascript.js");
        },
        onServerError : function (e) {
            alert("An error occured");
        },
        responseHandling : SMF.Net.ResponseHandling.forceFile
    });
function Page1_cntDownload_OnPressed(e) {
    webClientDownload.run();
}
```

Comment: alert('File has been downloaded as ' + this.response.nativePath); cammand gives undefined. Can we download into assest folder?